# Play framework 2.1.1 eclipse

Tags: eclipse, heroku, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to eclipsify a play project that I use with heroku.
I've downloaded and unzipped the play 2.1.1
According to the documentation I run this command in my project directory: 
play eclipse

And I get this errors
                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I've found some answers about setting the build.propeties file but it is already set. I don't know what to do. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the build.properties file and the dependencies in the Build.scala?

Answer (score 1):

Need PROJECT/project/build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.12.2
```

file content is only 1 line

refer : http://jackviers.blogspot.kr/2012/01/sbt-scalas-simple-build-tool-series.html

Answer (score 0):

On Github, James Ward and Matt Raible provided a comparison application for Play! framework 2 and Grails.

If you switch betsween branches, you will find their presentation slides too.

https://github.com/jamesward/happytrails